# Chrome console won't continue with code when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, console, google-developers-console

I'm trying to run a code in Google Chrome console, but the problem is that the page is reloading and each time it reloads the code stops and getting removed from the console.

Is there any way to stop this?

Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
document.getElementById("g1").checked = true;
document.getElementById("wr").submit();
window.location.href = 'https://www.webpage.com/?site=second'; //Here the code stops and get removed.
document.getElementById("b4").checked = true; //I want it to continue here
document.getElementById("we").submit();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the preserve log feature for this:

[image]